# What kind of mysql function for this query?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I don't know if this post is duplicate.I found some php file which consist of `JQuery DataTable` and was made by someone(I don't know where the developer lies).

[Clientside](http://pastebin.com/AMkh9)

[Serverside](http://pastebin.com/vphd4gEG)

This query's function is to show data inside Database, The query like:

```
case 'average' :
                $needfieldname=false;
                $month=getVar('calcmonth');
                $sql="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ID,name,remark,avrusepmonth 
                , CONCAT('<input type=''checkbox''id=''cb' , ID ,''' name=''check[]'' value=''',ID,''' >'
                ,'<label class=''lbcb'' for=''cb', ID,'''><=update=</label>') as checkb 
                , moq, leadtime 
                FROM test_media ";
                break;
```

what I want to ask here is this part :

```
monthavrage(ID,".$month.") as latestavr
```

what kind of Mysql function at query above? cause I got an error like:

```
FUNCTION TestMediaControl.monthavrage does not exist
```

Comment: EWWWWWW... generating html in the database? Kill that query with fire (or nuke it from orbit) and put the html generation where it belongs... in the client. As well, mysql uses backslashes to escape single quotes. Use `\'` instead of `''`.

Comment: It's probably a user-defined function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @SayemAhmed: first this page can work, but after some user forgot to hit update button every 25th in each month this page show error. so, I want to trace where is the root cause and found that function.But, i am not found any declaration before mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a SQL file which declare of monthavrage function.
I'm just need to execute this file, so my problem is disappear.

```
USE testmediacontrol;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS  monthavrage;


delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION monthavrage (mediaID MEDIUMINT ,amonth DECIMAL(2)) RETURNS DECIMAL(6,2)
BEGIN
        DECLARE avguse DECIMAL(6,2);
        DECLARE howlongmonth DECIMAL(2);

        SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),startuse)/30.4 
            INTO howlongmonth from media_use 
            WHERE media_ID=mediaID
            ORDER BY startuse 
            LIMIT 0,1;
        IF howlongmonth < amonth THEN
            SET amonth=howlongmonth;
        END IF;
        IF amonth <= 0 THEN
            RETURN 0;
        END IF;
        SELECT count(*)/amonth 
            INTO avguse from media_use 
            WHERE media_ID=mediaID and startuse  BETWEEN SUBDATE(now(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and  now();
        RETURN avguse;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FUNCTION TestMediaControl.monthavrage does not exist
```

IF the associated error code is 1305, that means MySQL is looking for the stored procedure 'monthavrage', and can't find it.

Comment: yes of course I now that, but this query for the first can work normally, see at my comment to Sayed Ahmed.